# Как изменить имя объекта в JSON-файле?

Tags: php, json

Есть JSON-файл вида:

```
{
'Org1': [
    {
        'a': 1
        'b': 2
    },
    {
        'a': 12
        'b': 345
    },
    {
        'a': 12364
        'b': -1
    }
],
'Org2': [
...
]
}
```

Как изменить только название объекта (например,'Org1' на 'Org123'), не меняя при этом его порядок и содержимое?

Answer (score 2):

К примеру, так:

```
$json = '{
"Org1": [
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
},
{
    "a": 12,
    "b": 345
},
{
    "a": 12364,
    "b": -1
}
],
"Org2": [

]
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$decoded['Org123'] = $decoded['Org1'];
unset($decoded['Org1']);
$json = json_encode($decoded);
echo $json;
```

Порядок изменится. Если не хотите менять порядок, нужно использовать регулярные выражения или писать свой парсер JSON.
К тому же, у вас невалидный JSON: пропущены запятые при перечислении и ипользуются одинарные кавычки вместо двойных.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью регулярки так:

```
$str = <<<STR
{
'Org1': [
    {
        'a': 1
        'b': 2
    },
    {
        'a': 12
        'b': 345
    },
    {
        'a': 12364
        'b': -1
    }
],
STR;

$str = preg_replace("/^'Org1'/m", "Org123", $str);
```